# Calculating multiple aggregated values and calculating their final sum all in 1 column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

So I have a column where I do a string_agg in a table as follows

```
select buildingid, string_agg(distinct cast(obligatioNr as varchar(2)), ', ') as SPJ
...
```

the values of this field has values between 0-12

[image]

I want the total values of each number and all this stored in the final line in 1 column.

[image]

My code is along the lines of

```
with results as 
(
    select  id, amount, SPJ
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT building.id as ids,
            count(distinct s.studentnr) as amount,
            string_agg(distinct cast(so.obligationnr as varchar(2)), ', ') as SPJ,

        from ....

        GROUP BY building.id
    ) t

    GROUP BY ids, amount,SPJ

    ORDER BY ids
)
    SELECT *
    FROM results 
    UNION all
    SELECT NULL as ids,
    SUM(amount),
    null as SPJ
    FROM results
```

I am using Postgres 9.3

Comment: not a complete solution, just a starter: concat the possible values as a string, replace one possible value and count the difference of the char_length, eg select '11' || ':' ||  (char_length('8,9,9,10,11,2,3,8,12,7,10') -  char_length( replace('8,9,9,10,11,2,3,8,12,7,10', '11', ''))) / char_length('11')

Comment: To increase speed, you can use that range of values is limited to 0..12. You can write a function with accumulator array like _counts[13], loop over all values and increase _counts[] at index corresponding to found value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if

```
db-# select v from t;
    v
---------
 8,9
 9,10,11
(2 rows)
```

then:

```
db=# with t(v) as (values('8,9'),('9,10,11'))
,m  as (select unnest(string_to_array(v,',')) u from t)
select u||':'||count(u) from m group by u order by u::int;
 ?column?
----------
 8:1
 9:2
 10:1
 11:1
(4 rows)
```

finally:

```
db=# with t(v) as (values('8,9'),('9,10,11'))
,m  as (select unnest(string_to_array(v,',')) u from t)
,f as (select u||':'||count(u) a from m group by u order by u::int)
select string_agg(a,',') from f;
    string_agg
-------------------
 8:1,9:2,10:1,11:1
(1 row)
```

ah, and all together:

```
db=# with t(v) as (values('8,9'),('9,10,11'))
,m  as (select unnest(string_to_array(v,',')) u from t)
,f as (select u||':'||count(u) a from m group by u order by u::int)
select v from t union all select string_agg(a,',') from f;
         v
-------------------
 8,9
 9,10,11
 8:1,9:2,10:1,11:1
(3 rows)
```

Comment: the ,m and the ,f are those temporary tables? is it possible to create multiple tables in such a way?

Comment: those are cte aliases

Answer (score 0):

I would use two levels of aggregation:

```
select string_agg(o2 || ':' || cnt, ', ') as all_values
from (select cast(obligatioNr as varchar(2)) as o2,
             count(distinct buildingid) as cnt
      from . . .
      group by o2
     ) x;
```